# Getting duration between two dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime, form

I'm developing on a web application where I have a start and a finish date and time and have to set the duration between it.

There are inputs for dates and times.

Then, I have this function which calculates the duration between the two of them, and they are working properly. The duration, though, needs to be dynamic. So, i made this piece of code, creating a "on" on each of then, so that when it changes, they mount an object with the four datetime values and then call it to the getDuration function.

```
$(document.body).on('change','.data-inicio > input',function () {
    var tr   = $(this).parent().parent();
    var time = {
        dstart:  dateDbToView($(this).val()),
        hstart:  tr.find('.hora-inicio').find('input').val(),
        dfinish: dateDbToView(tr.find('.data-final').find('input').val()),
        hfinish: tr.find('.hora-final').find('input').val()
    };
    var drc = getDuration(time.dstart, time.hstart, time.dfinish, time.hfinish);
    tr.find('.duracao').find('input').val(drc);
});

$(document.body).on('change','.hora-inicio > input',function () {
    var tr   = $(this).parent().parent();
    var time = {
        dstart:  dateDbToView(tr.find('.data-inicio').find('input').val()),
        hstart:  $(this).val(),
        dfinish: dateDbToView(tr.find('.data-final').find('input').val()),
        hfinish: tr.find('.hora-final').find('input').val()
    };
    var drc = getDuration(time.dstart, time.hstart, time.dfinish, time.hfinish);
    tr.find('.duracao').find('input').val(drc);
});

$(document.body).on('change','.data-final > input',function () {
    var tr   = $(this).parent().parent();
    var time = {
        dstart:  dateDbToView(tr.find('.data-inicio').find('input').val()),
        hstart:  tr.find('.hora-inicio').find('input').val(),
        dfinish: dateDbToView($(this).val()),
        hfinish: tr.find('.hora-final').find('input').val()
    };
    var drc = getDuration(time.dstart, time.hstart, time.dfinish, time.hfinish);
    tr.find('.duracao').find('input').val(drc);
});

$(document.body).on('change','.hora-final > input',function () {
    var tr   = $(this).parent().parent();
    var time = {
        dstart:  dateDbToView(tr.find('.data-inicio').find('input').val()),
        hstart:  tr.find('.hora-inicio').find('input').val(),
        dfinish: dateDbToView(tr.find('.data-final').find('input').val()),
        hfinish: $(this).val()
    };
    var drc = getDuration(time.dstart, time.hstart, time.dfinish, time.hfinish);
    tr.find('.duracao').find('input').val(drc);
});
```

My question is: this looks pretty confusing for anyone but me, which can be an bad point when it comes about maintenance. There must be a better way of making this work, so, I'm asking for suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

All of the change handlers are basically the same.  You could roll them all into one by using smarter jQuery selectors.

Also, the `time` object is pointless.  You can just use four separate variables.  I've also moved the `dateDbToView()` calls to declutter the `tr.find(…)` lines so that the parallelism is more obvious.

```
$('.data-inicio, .hora-inicio, .data-final, .hora-final').on('change', 'input', function() {
    var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
    var dStart = tr.find('.data-inicio > input').val();
    var hStart = tr.find('.hora-inicio > input').val();
    var dFinish = tr.find('.data-final > input').val();
    var hFinish = tr.find('.hora-final > input').val();

    tr.find('.duracao > input').val(duration(
        dateDbToView(dStart),  hStart,
        dateDbToView(dFinish), hFinish
    ));
});
```

I suggest renaming `getDuration(…)` to `duration(…)`, because it is performing a calculation, rather than retrieving information that already exists.  (For the same reason, we say `Math.sin(…)` rather than `Math.getSin(…)`).

Comment: Wow, thanks! I really didn't realized i could pass the classes all together on one selector!

For the duration function name, i just renamed it, makes a lot more of sense!